# Running out of memory when using hundreds of same Image

Tags: memory, react-native, uiimage, marker, react-native-maps

#### Description

I am using react-native-maps to draw about 750 markers on the map.
Each marker is using same Image

#### Reproduction Steps and Sample Code

```
const markerImage = <Image source={images.marker} />;
export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
        { coordinates.map(coordinate => {
          return (
            <Marker
              key={coordinate.id}
              coordinate={coordinate}
              children={markerImage}
            />
          );
        })}
      </MapView>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Possible Solution

Re-using UIImage
[Optimising custom marker image performance with Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555778/optimising-custom-marker-image-performance-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

However, I do not know how to do this in React Native as React abstracts away the view layer.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: ["0.41.2"]
- react-native-maps: ["^0.13.0"]
- Platform: [both]
- Development Operating System: [MacOS]
- Dev tools: [Xcode: 8.3, iPhone 7(10.3), GalaxyS6(6.0.1)]

[image]

[image]